# BASH Scripting assistance needed

Tags: bash

Well, I am currently a novice shell scripter. I have a basic knowledge of other programming languages such as Javascript for HTML, JScript, VB.NET, and C++. (C++ Not so much, just dipped my feet in the water for that). Most recently, my recent project has been attempting to learn as much as I can about Bash shell scripting. The current issue is understanding status error codes, as well as checking if certain parameters contain directories or if it exists at all. I am working from a book, with tutorials and review questions. Unfortunately there is no answer key, or even hints for that matter.

- Display an error message and exit with status 1 if no parameters are given
- Display an error message and exit with status 2 if source is not a directory
- Display an error message and exit with status 3 if destination does not exist or is not a directory

The above is what I must do, so far the first one I believe I have done correctly, if not please, correct me, or guide me in the proper direction. As I learn best when samples are given, I thought I would ask for assistance.

```
if [ $? ]; then
  echo "You must supply at least one parameter"
  exit 1
fi
  #The above is the part I am pretty sure is correct.


if [ $? -d $directory "$1" ]; then
  echo "$directory is not a directory"
  exit 2
fi
#The above was self written. I am almost positive it is wrong.

if [ $? -lt 2 ]; then
  set "$1" .pwd
fi
#the above was given to me from the book as a reference point to start (tutorial)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$?` is the return code of a command you execute. Maybe you are thinking it's a return code of the current script. In any case it's not doing what you think it's doing.

All of my examples assume your command is run like so: `script [source] [destination]`

Error message if no parameters are given:

```
if [ ! "$#" ]; then
     echo "please supply a parameter"
     exit 1
fi
```

Display error if source is not a directory

```
if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
     echo "$1 is not a directory"
     exit 2
fi
```

Display error if destination doesn't exist or isn't a directory

```
if [ ! -d "$2" ]; then
     echo "$2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory"
     exit 3
fi
```

Comment: There should be a space between `if` and `[`. `$1` and `$2` should be quoted to avoid field splitting and pathname generation. `||` separates commands so you need `if [ ! -e "$2" ] || [ ! -d "$2" ]; then` (although the `-e` test is redundant here, `-d` already returns false if it does not exist).

Comment: Wow, now that you state it, I should have gotten it on my own. I have not even attempted to try it on my own shell, but just from looking at it, it appears to be 100% correct. I appreciate the fast response. Thank you.

Comment: @user518073 - no problem. Make sure to check the edits I did per @jiles suggestions.

Comment: I did not even notice the mistakes, I typed them properly, the spaces as well as the "$1", however, the redundant -e has been noted.

Comment: Checking for an empty `$1` can be tricked into a false negative (even though an empty parameter is not always useful). It's best to check `$#` explicitly.

Comment: @Ignacio - true. I didn't think about $#. I fixed it again :-D